# Get header to align with top of page

Tags: html, css

I'm having this weird problem with this website I just started building. I want to get the header to align completely flush with the top of the page. But for some reason, there's a small space, about 20px high, that won't go away no matter what I try. I'm assuming there's just something about CSS and html that I'm not getting so can you guys help me out?

**CSS**:

```css
#header {
    background-color:#3429C9;
    /*-webkit-border-radius:15px;
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    border-radius:15px;*/
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    margin-top:-20px;
    border-bottom:2px solid white;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    height:60px;
}

body {
    text-align:center;
    font-family: Georgia, Serif;
    background: #000000;
    margin:0;
    height:100px;
    display:block;
    border:2px solid red;
}
```

Comment: can you post your codes here and see what we can do www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: I think you need to post the content of your header and its css as undoubtedly that's what's pushing it down.

Comment: I think I actually figured it out. For some reason that I don't quite understand, when I gave my header a padding of 1px, it aligned. Thanks anyway guys!.

Comment: Read my answer below to understand why, you should really try to understand what you are doing or you'll get in a lot of trouble...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every browser (firefox,chrome,IE) have a default CSS it comes with which give default styling to elements. It also gives some default margin/padding, so usually when starting a web site design you should use a [css reset file](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to reset all default styling.

That way you get the same basic behaviour for all browsers.

For a quick solution to yuor problem, just set the header padding/margin to 0.

Comment: Yeah to be honest, I didn't even know about css reset files so I owe you one for that. That seems to have fixed the issue without using a padding in my file. Thanks!